# Why JavaScript getTime() is not a function?

Tags: javascript, function, date, gettime

I used the following function:

```
function datediff()
{
  var dat1 = document.getElementById('date1').value;
  alert(dat1);//i get 2010-04-01
  var dat2 = document.getElementById('date2').value;
  alert(dat2);// i get 2010-04-13
 
  var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;   // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
  var diffDays = Math.abs((dat1.getTime() - dat2.getTime())/(oneDay));
  alert(diffDays);
}
```

I get the error:

> ```
> dat1.getTime()` is not a function
> ```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

That's because your `dat1` and `dat2` variables are just strings.

You should parse them to get a `Date` object, for that format I always use the following function:

```
// parse a date in yyyy-mm-dd format
function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
  // new Date(year, month [, date [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])
  return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]); // months are 0-based
}
```

I use this function because the [`Date.parse(string)`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.9.4.2) (or `new Date(string)`) method is *implementation dependent*, and the *yyyy-MM-dd* format will work on modern browser but *not* on IE, so I prefer doing it manually.

Answer (score 70):

For all those who came here and did indeed use Date typed Variables, here is the solution I found. It does also apply to TypeScript.

I was facing this error because I tried to compare two dates using the following Method

```
var res = dat1.getTime() > dat2.getTime(); // or any other comparison operator
```

However Im sure I used a Date object, because Im using angularjs with typescript, and I got the data from a typed API call.

Im not sure why the error is raised, but I assume that because my Object was created by JSON deserialisation, possibly the `getTime()` method was simply not added to the prototype.

#### Solution

In this case, recreating a date-Object based on your dates will fix the issue.

```
var res = new Date(dat1).getTime() > new Date(dat2).getTime()
```

#### Edit:

I was right about this. Types will be cast to the according type but they wont be instanciated. Hence there will be a string cast to a date, which will obviously result in a runtime exception.

The trick is, if you use interfaces with non primitive only data such as dates or functions, you will need to perform a mapping after your http request.

```
class Details {
    description: string;
    date: Date;
    score: number;
    approved: boolean;

    constructor(data: any) {
      Object.assign(this, data);
    }
}
```

and to perform the mapping:

```
public getDetails(id: number): Promise<Details> {
    return this.http
               .get<Details>(`${this.baseUrl}/api/details/${id}`)
               .map(response => new Details(response.json()))
               .toPromise();
}
```

for arrays use:

```
public getDetails(): Promise<Details[]> {
    return this.http
               .get<Details>(`${this.baseUrl}/api/details`)
               .map(response => {
                   const array = JSON.parse(response.json()) as any[];
                   const details = array.map(data => new Details(data));
                   return details;
               })
               .toPromise();
}
```

For [credits and further information](https://davidpine.net/blog/angular-http-gotchas/) about this topic follow the link.

Comment: yep, exactly my issue is well. Just another thing to add to the "reasons why JS sucks"

Comment: Yea not the best error message in history. Anyway in hindsight, I'd propably rephrase my answer a little. Apparently using typescript interfaces in angular does nothing, but hide the json data object behind the interface. That's why the date string won't be converted to a proper date format by itself.

Answer (score 13):

To use this function/method,you need an instance of the class **Date** .

This method is always used in conjunction with a **Date** object.

See the code below :

```
var d = new Date();
d.getTime();
```

Link : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getTime.asp

Answer (score 6):

dat1 and dat2 are Strings in JavaScript. There is no getTime function on the String prototype. I believe you want the Date.parse() function: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp

You would use it like this:

```
var date = Date.parse(dat1);
```

Comment: I woud say that it should be `var date = new Date(Date.parse(dat1));`

Comment: @Hexodus: Why is that?

Comment: @EdS. You're right - Both ways will produce the same result so one should use Rayan's solution because it's shorter.

Answer (score 2):

It's a time format problem
change it by following.

```
Date.parse(dat1)
```

instead of

```
dat1.getTime()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could conditionally check if the value is a Date object in the following way.

```
const d1 = new Date();

if (typeof d1 === 'object' && d1 !== null && 'getTime' in d1) {
  const result = d1.getTime();
  console.log(result); // ️ 163966...
}
```

https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-typeerror-date-gettime-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

solution : we can convert `yourdate` to String then call `Date.parse()` method.

```
var d0 = yourDate.toString();
var d1 = new Date(Date.parse(d0));
```