# javascript Date().getTime() is not a function

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to compare some Dates in javascript.

For some reason, I'm getting "Tue May 01 2012 16:43:03 GMT+0900 (JST) has no method 'getTime'"

Of course, [strings don't have methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627650/why-javascript-gettime-is-not-a-function)

I started with this code inside a callback, but it was failing at `getTime()` on the line that creates `var age`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array_of_usage_indices.length; i++) {
    store.get(array_of_usage_indices[i]['key'],function(may_need_gc) {
        if(may_need_gc) {
            var now = Date();
            var created = Date(may_need_gc['value']);
            var age = now.getTime()-created.getTime();
        }
    })
}
```

I've pared it down so my example page is literally just this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>date test</title>

    </head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            var now = Date();
            alert(now.getTime());
            var t = Date().getTime();
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

This is failing in Chrome 18.0.1025.168 and Firefox 13.0.

Screenshots of what I've tried:

[image: screenshot no method 'getTime']

[image: screenshot no method 'getTime']

So my question:

<strike>wth?</strike>

Do I have to use ParseDate()?  Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try using `new` keyword to instantiate a new object
so instead of this

```
var now = Date();
```

try this

```
var now = new Date();
```

Comment: @clocksmith `Date.now()` (note: no parens) does work, `.getTime()` needs a Date object. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517359/performance-date-now-vs-date-gettime Docs:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

Comment: Awesome that it works, but my question is WHY?

Answer (score 29):

You need to use the `new` operator to create a Date object.

```
(new Date()).getTime()
```

Comment: Thank you.  I've given the green check to Parv because it seems you're okay on points for now.  ;-)

Answer (score 10):

This will make 'now' as variable type as date:

```
var now = new Date();
```

This will get you time from 'now':

```
new Date(now).getTime();
```

Answer (score -1):

this works:
dateX is passed in as a variable of type date

```
fctDateToLong(dateX: Date|string|number): number 
  {
    return new Date(dateX).getTime() 
   }
```

I am not 100% sure why this works so will not comment on the why. Good luck.

you also try this where dateX is of Date Type.

```
const newDate = new Date(dateX.toString()).getTime()
```