# Performance - Date.now() vs Date.getTime()

Tags: javascript, timestamp

```
var timeInMs = Date.now();
```

per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

vs.

```
var timeInMs = new Date(optional).getTime();
```

per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).

Is there any difference between the two, besides the syntax and the ability to set the Date (to not the current) via optional in the second version?

`Date.now()` is faster - check out the [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/gettime-vs-now-0)

Comment: for anyone who cares, Date.now() doesn’t work in Internet Explorer versions earlier than IE9. I myself don't care

Comment: For what it's worth, you can add the compatibility shim mentioned in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now to make Date.now() work on IE<9, too.

Comment: http://jsben.ch/#/TOF9y

Answer (score 146):

These things are the same (*edit* semantically; performance is a little better with `.now()`):

```
var t1 = Date.now();
var t2 = new Date().getTime();
```

However, the time value from any already-created `Date` instance is frozen at the time of its construction (or at whatever time/date it's been set to). That is, if you do this:

```
var now = new Date();
```

and then wait a while, a subsequent call to `now.getTime()` will tell the time at the point the variable was set.

Comment: Do you think it would be more performant to create one date object in the beginnign of the program and then just update that date object (`dateObj.setTime(Date.now())`) or create new date objects every time you do something asynchronous that needs to access `Date` methods (such as `dateObj.getMinutes()`) ?

Comment: @Taurus modern JavaScript runtimes are *extremely* good at object creation and garbage collection. Unless you're working on some sort of real-time game kernel, there's no reason at all to worry about it. Write code that looks good and isn't fragile.

Comment: not supposed to say thanks but thanks (I hope I haven't done this more than once).

Answer (score 79):

They are effectively equivalent, but you should use `Date.now()`. It's clearer and about twice as fast.

Edit: Source: http://jsperf.com/date-now-vs-new-date

Comment: Is this because `Date(optional).getTime();` has to allocate space to get a new Date object before getting the current time?

Comment: Probably, yes. I would expect that it has more to do with everything that the Date constructor is doing rather than the actual allocation of the object, though.

Comment: Yeah, I added that hasily - I meant the allocation and everything that goes along with creating an object.

Comment: @vegemite4me Mentioned link is broken!

Comment: @cmcodes Not my answer, but you can try this: https://jsbench.me/f5k9ckm6lh/1

Comment: It is important to note the absolute performance of these things in addition to the relative performance. The slowest one ran 4 million times per second for me.  Which means the most important takeaway for my purposes is to take care not to do any of these hundreds of times per frame (which I would instinctively avoid already, but it's easy to lose track). But since I can avoid that, I should use whichever one is otherwise most useful.

Answer (score 6):

When you do `(new Date()).getTime()` you are creating a new Date object. If you do this repeatedly, it will be about 2x slower than Date.now()

The same principle should apply for `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)` vs `[].slice.call(arguments, 0)`

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it's preferable to keep some time tracking variable in a Date object format rather than as just a number of milliseconds, to have access to Date's methods without re-instantiating. In that case, Date.now() still wins over new Date() or the like, though only by about 20% on my Chrome and by a tiny amount on IE.

See my JSPERF on

```
timeStamp2.setTime(Date.now()); // set to current;
```

vs.

```
timeStamp1 = new Date(); // set to current;
```

http://jsperf.com/new-date-vs-settime

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct; they are effectively equivalent when using the current time.

Answer (score 1):

**Date.now()** call the static method and this is enough to be preferred, perfoming a test:

```
# cat test.ts

const limit = 10000000 //ten milion
let startTime = Date.now()
let val = 0

for (let i=0; i<=limit; i++) {
    const val1 = Date.now()
}

let diff = Date.now() - startTime

console.log('Time Date.now(): ' + diff + ' ms')

startTime = Date.now()
val=0
for (let i=0; i<=limit; i++) {
    const val1 = new Date().getTime()
}

diff = Date.now() - startTime

console.log('Time with new Date().getTime: ' + diff + ' ms' )
```

Test execution:

```
# node test.ts
Time Date.now(): 818 ms
Time with new Date().getTime: 1625 ms
```

Date.now() is 50% faster

Answer (score -2):

`Date.now()` is calling the static method `now()` of the class `Date`.
While `new Date().getTime()` can be divided into two steps:

1. `new Date()`: Call the `constructor()` method of `Date` class to initialize an instance of `Date` class.
2. Call `getTime()` method of the instance we just initialize.

[MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) classifies `Date.now()` into static method of `Date`, and `Date.prototype.getTime()` into instance method.