# what does "var now = +new Date()" do in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was looking through some code. [this code](http://www.gabrielgambetta.com/client-side-prediction-live-demo.html), to be exact (the script is inline with the html. [here it is on hastebin](https://www.hastebin.com/oyefuyuruv.http)).

In the code, I came across the following line:

```
var now = +new Date();
```

I am a bit confused by what it does. Here are my thoughts so far:

At first, I thought that maybe it is just a different way of writing `a += x`. However, I have disproven that theory based on the fact that `now` is initialized in the same line, and you can't do `var a += x;`

My final theory is that `var a = +new B();` is the same thing as `var a = new Date.now();`, so something like `var time = +new Date();` would be equivalent to `var time = new Date.time();`. I came to this conclusion because of the fact that the next line, `var render_timestamp = now - (1000.0 / server.update_rate);` subtracts a number from `now`, and since `new Date()` returns `yyyy-mm-tttt:hh:mm.ss`, `var now = +new Date();` must somehow return a number, so that the next line is able to do arithmetic on it.

Can anybody explain what this syntax (`var a = +new B();`)? Any insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221539/what-does-the-plus-sign-do-in-new-date

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255664/new-date-is-this-good-practice

Comment: Unary operators

Comment: did you try to just test it in the console, like `console.log(+someValue)`? btw, what does `var a = -someVariable;`?