# Date() vs Date().getTime()

Tags: javascript, date

What is the difference between using `new Date()` and `new Date().getTime()` when subtracting two timestamps? ([test script on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TSapP/1/))

Both of the following gives the same results:

```javascript
var prev1 = new Date();
setTimeout(function() {
    var curr1 = new Date();
    var diff1 = curr1 - prev1;
}, 500);

var prev2 = new Date().getTime();
setTimeout(function() {
    var curr2 = new Date().getTime();
    var diff2 = curr2 - prev2;
}, 500);
```

Is there a reason I should prefer one over another?

Comment: No difference AFAIK `new Date()` will return the time in ms upon instantiation.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517359/just-sytnax-date-now-vs-date-gettime

Comment: @Moe I am asking `new Date()` vs `new Date().getTime()`, not `Date.now()`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I get that it wasn't in your questions, but you may want to consider `Date.now()` which is fastest because you don't need to instantiate a new `Date` object, see the following for a comparison of the different versions:
http://jsperf.com/date-now-vs-new-date-gettime/8

The above link shows using `new Date()` is faster than `(new Date()).getTime()`, but that `Date.now()` is faster than them all.

Browser support for `Date.now()` isn't even that bad (IE9+):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

Comment: For some reason jsperf shows that `(new Date()).getTime()` is faster, than `+ new Date();` any idea why?

Answer (score 4):

when you create a new Date() object it is automagically initialized to the current time.

From W3Schools:

```
new Date() // current date and time
new Date(milliseconds) //milliseconds since 1970/01/01
new Date(dateString)
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

The getTime() function simply returns that time.

From W3Schools:

```
Date.getTime() // method returns the number of milliseconds between midnight of January 1, 1970 and the specified date.
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: I'm not sure whether my reading comprehension is off or whether you aren't explaining `getTime()` correctly.  It sounds like you are saying the value of getTime() will change between the time when the `Date` object is created when when the function is called.  That's not what you meant, was it?

Answer (score 4):

Date arithmetic converts dates to Epoch time (milliseconds since Jan 1 1970), which is why functionally the two code snippets are the same.

As for which is faster, Jamund Ferguson's answer is correct.