# performance.now() vs Date.now()

Tags: javascript, time, performance.now

What is the difference between `performance.now()` and `Date.now()`?

Should I consider `performance.now()` as a replacement for `Date.now()` since `performace.now()` is more consistent and independent?

Comment: No! `Date.now()`returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC, `performance.now()` returns the number of milliseconds/microseconds elapsed since *an arbitrary epoch*. Basically, `performance.now()` should only be used when you want to measure the relative distance between two time points, not their "absolute" position in time.

Comment: What @buttifulbuttefly says, plus ... `performance.now` offers more precise timing (sub-millisecond precision).

Comment: Indeed, more precise *timing*, not more precise *time*.

Comment: @markE This is not true anymore. Due to [Spectre](https://spectreattack.com/), the precision of `performance.now` [is being limited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now)

Comment: **Compare To**: [Date.now() vs Date.getTime()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12517359/1366033)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

They both serve different purposes.

`performance.now()` is **relative to page load** and more precise in orders of magnitude. Use cases include benchmarking and other cases where a high-resolution time is required such as media (gaming, audio, video, etc.)

It should be noted that `performance.now()` is only available in newer browsers (including IE10+).

`Date.now()` is **relative to the Unix epoch** (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z) and dependent on system clock. Use cases include same old date manipulation ever since the beginning of JavaScript.

See [When milliseconds are not enough: `performance.now`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/When-milliseconds-are-not-enough-performance-now?hl=en) and [`now` method (Internet Explorer) - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973355(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information.

The official W3C spec can be found here: [High Resolution Time API](http://www.w3.org/TR/hr-time/)

Comment: That precision comes at a cost.  It's 50% slower.  Good to know if you need it in a tight loop. https://jsperf.com/perf-vs-date/1

Comment: Oops, I meant 80% slower.  :-(

Comment: Keep in mind what google audits think about date.now()    https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/date-now

Comment: currently in Firefox performance.now() is like 20% faster but in other browsers suprasingly slower like 60% - you can check for yourselfs: https://jsbench.me/s6jz9v29i3/1

Comment: 3x slower on my Raspberry Firefox. performance.now() seems not performant but is more precise. A few hundred measures will not affect performance anyway.

Comment: @StLia what do they think? That links actually points back here.

Comment: why does developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/date-now redirect to this stackoverflow question

Comment: It's only **10x** more accurate: see my post at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70545051/15012953

Comment: Practically, it's not any more accurate. performance.now gets rounded to millisecond precision in [both Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) and [WebKit](https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/226495/webkit), so unless you're developing two different codebases, one for Chrome, and one for FF/Safari.

Answer (score 31):

`Date.now()` returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC, `performance.now()` returns the number of milliseconds, with microseconds in the fractional part, from `performance.timing.navigationStart`, the start of navigation of the document, to the `performance.now()` call. Another important difference between `Date.now()` and `performance.now()` is that the latter is monotonically increasing, so the difference between two calls will never be negative.

For better understanding visit the [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/discovering-the-high-resolution-time-api/).

Answer (score 12):

The first thing I noticed was that `performance.now()` is **4 times** slower than `Date.now()` (400k operations vs 100k on my computer). However, if you want accurate timing/time since page load, using `performance.now()` is the better option. It's purely dependent on the time since the code started running, and clock changes do *not* affect the time. It's also more accurate: counting tenths of a millisecond instead of milliseconds.

**TL;DR**

On non-Firefox browsers, `Date.now()` is accurate to `~1ms` and `performance.now()` is accurate to `~0.1ms` unless in certain cases. If you're using Firefox, the accuracy is down for both to `2ms`. They are both extremely fast.

**Support and Speed**

As for support, `Date.now()` has slightly more support than `performance.now()`, as both are supported by modern browsers, *and even Internet Explorer 10 and 11*.

`new Date().getTime()` has just a bit more support and is **2x** slower than `Date.now()`. It's slower, because it creates a big object, but only calls a single function.

However, this [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=performance.now()) page shows that `performance.now()` is almost always okay, in 98.25% (as of right now) of cases.

(From here on out I will only refer to `Date.now()`, but `new Date.getTime()` is the same in the cases below)

**Usage**

`Date.now()` can (and should) be used for delta time (particularly `requestAnimationFrame()`: it can easily get the correct frame on a 120fps display! It can also be used as a clock. It counts how many milliseconds have passed since the Unix Epoch (see the top answer for more details).

A particularly interesting use case is calling `Date.now()` multiple times in one frame in order to stop calculations after a certain amount of time has passed. As `Date.now()` is pretty fast, this shouldn't be much of an issue.

For applications that require a bit more accuracy (see below), `performance.now()` can be used. It behaves the exact same as `Date.now()` if you're using a timer (because it still counts up in milliseconds), except it's more accurate.

To use `performance.now()` as a (usually) more accurate `Date.now()` or object, add `performance.timing.navigationStart` to the value. This does *seem* to be a few milliseconds off from the `Date.now()` object, but as to why I'm not sure. Just don't combine the two

**Accuracy**

From what I can tell, **`performance.now()` is only 10x more accurate** compared to `Date.now()` on my Chrome desktop: considering time leaps of 0.1ms, However, this accuracy is good enough for most time-strict applications. (Read the Firefox section for more info on their accuracy.) It may look more accurate (like `313015.59999999404`), but it's not: it is intentionally limited for security reasons, because the exploitation of time could allow malicious code to [access other applications](https://spectreattack.com/). If you want it to not show up in such an ugly way, you can use `performance.now().toFixed(1)` to make it more accurate. You can also make this a `Number` by adding a plus sign to the start: `+performance.now().toFixed(1)` should work.

**Firefox**

Sadly, this performance (of 0.1ms) **is not possible** if you have Firefox users and do not have access to Cross-Origin headers. Instead, you can only get an accuracy of 2ms (also the same as `Date.now()`!) In order to enable it, put the `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin` and `Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp` in your document. Users can also increase this speed to 100ms (or higher). Visit the [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) documentation for more information.

Comment: This is not a floating point issue, precision is [intentionally limited now to mitigate Spectre and other issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now)