# Get the timing when data renderd in a react component in reactjs hook

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

I want to get the time when a table is rendered with its Data,
Is this code  I can correctly get the time? I don't know when useEffect triggered with   `tableDataRenderedTime`, will that data has been updated to table

```
const [tableData,setTableData] = useState([])
const [tableDataRenderedTime,setTableDataRenderedTime] = useState(false)


useEffect(()=>{

...
const data = await getData({...})
setTableData(data)
setTableDataRenderedTime(true) // <---- 
...


},[])

useEffect(()=>{
 const time = performance.now() // <---- Is this the time when the table renderd with new Data??

},[tableDataRenderedTime])



return (

<TableComponent data={data}/>
)
```

Comment: What's the react native version you're using ? [performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) API may not work in release builds.

Comment: Im using Reactjs in html5 @PasinduDilshan

is this method correct to get the time the table data rendered?

Answer (score 0):

`performance.now()` is relative to the page load. If you need to get the exact time when table was rendered you can use `Date.now()`.

```js
...
useEffect(()=>{
 const time = Date.now() // Exact time in milliseconds when table data gets updated. (milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970)

},[tableDataRenderedTime])
...
```

[Here's a good SO thread on `performance.now()` vs `Date.now()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795525/performance-now-vs-date-now).

*`performance.now()` is useful if you need to measure the time taken to update table data. To do so within first `useEffect` hook, you can do following.*

```js
const [tableData,setTableData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
...
  const t0 = performance.now();
  const data = await getData({...});
  setTableData(data);
  setTableDataRenderedTime(true);
  const t1 = performance.now();
  const duration = t1 - t0 // Time elapsed to load table data
...
});
```

Comment: I don't know the mechanism in Reactjs(batch update..or something related to how it rendered)，after ```setTableDataRenderedTime(true) ``` ， I tried to get time in an effect hook ，it this the correct timing I want?(the exact time table has been renderd with new data..)