# Which on is better? Date.now() or new Date()

Tags: meteor

Is there any pros or cons? (in case of storing date inside database)

In Meteor _id field doesn't represent insert time.

Also. I know that MongoDB expireAfterSeconds TTL doesn't work with `Date.now()`
Seems like `new Date()` is more universal and you can always make `Date.now()` from it.

Anything else? This question is more about use cases. So if you had problems with any, let us know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to store date/time in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778428/best-way-to-store-date-time-in-mongodb)

Comment: `new Date()` returns an object that includes numerous methods. `Date.now()` simply returns an integer.

Comment: Better?  Depends on your use case.  Generally, `new Date()` will be more useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performance - Date.now() vs Date.getTime()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517359/performance-date-now-vs-date-gettime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Date()` is a much more object-oriented way of passing information around. It is generally the preferred method.

Comment: That actually isn't right at all. Both new Date() and Date.now() are both perfect in terms of OO, and are semantically the same. Date.now() should be preferred, because it is cleaner and faster.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/gettime-vs-now-0 @LucasSunsi You're right but it helps with the actual proof

Answer (score 0):

Actually, they are semantically equivalent, although Date.now() is much faster.