# Is the return value +new Date() different from Date.now()?

Tags: javascript, timestamp

Assuming I have two functions

```
function newDate(){
  return +new Date();
}
function dateNow(){
  return Date.now();
}
```

So I wonder if it makes a difference that one returns **+new Date()** and another **Date.now()**?

Comment: In your title and your post you wrote `+new Date()` did you mean this or did you mean `new Date()` without the `+` sign?

Comment: i'm mean **+new Date()**   with sign **+**

Answer (score 2):

According to the spec:

> **15.9.4.4 Date.now ( )**
>   The now function return a Number value that is the time value designating the UTC *date and time of the occurrence of the call to now*.
>
> **15.9.3.3 new Date ( )**
>   The [[PrimitiveValue]] internal property of the newly constructed object is set to the *time value (UTC) identifying the current time*.

Coercing the `Date` object created by `new Date()` to a number with the unary `+` operator results in the primitive value. So the question of whether your two cases are always the same boils down to whether the two things below are identical:

1. date and time of the occurrence of the call to now
2. the time value identifying the current time

It would seem to be a good bet that they are.

#### 3rd party edit

The chrome (v49) console returns this:

```
x = Date.now(), y1 = +new Date(), y2 = new Date();
x returns 1463201841680
y1 returns 1463201841680
y2 returns Sat May 14 2016 06:57:21 GMT+0200
```

Answer (score 1):

They give the same value. Verified in chrome devtools console

```
Date.now() === +new Date()
> true
```

However, performance is a little better with Date.now()

[Performance - Date.now() vs Date.getTime()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517359/performance-date-now-vs-date-gettime)

Comment: **Date.now()** return the **timestamp** or not ?

Comment: it does return a timestamp. Please mark as complete if you agree

Comment: ok.

will **+new Date()**  returns the numeric equivalent of the date or not ?

Comment: my answer indicates that they are numerical equivalents

Comment: In my chrome 49 this `Date.now() === new Date();` returns false and this 
`Date.now() === +new Date();`  returns true.