# Create timezone-aware date in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, date, mongoose

When I create objects in my MongoDB using Mongoose, the dates are formatted as, for instance, `2016-10-10T15:35:52.764Z` (it might be `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`). If I use `Date.now()` in JavaScript, I get a timestamp.

How can I create the same date format as Mongoose with javascript?

## Edit

It seems I can use

```
new Date().toISOString();
```

but what is the difference of, for instance, `Date.now()` and `new Date()`?

Are there any reasons for not using `new Date()` instead of a function under the `Date` object (that somehow already seems to be initialized without writing `new Date()`?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performance - Date.now() vs Date.getTime()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517359/performance-date-now-vs-date-gettime)

Comment: [*Date.now*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.now) returns a number, [*new Date*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-constructor-date) returns a Date object whose internal time value is exactly the same as if you'd called *Date.now*.

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment.js and run like this

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'); // print 2016-10-11T15:25:36
```