# Javascript date time stamp confusion

Tags: javascript, date

I've always wanted to know the difference between the two popular ways to get current timestamp in JS.

```
Date.now()
new Date().getTime()
```

What is the difference between the two? And if they are the same, why do we have two things that do the same job?

Comment: They do the same thing. The first one is just a shortcut when you want the time of now instead of some arbitrary `Date` object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Performance - Date.now() vs Date.getTime()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517359/performance-date-now-vs-date-gettime)

Comment: @Dortimer yep its helpful. Din know the .now way we 2x faster. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12517413/4052745. 
In simple terms they are basically the same thing, but it is suggested to use Date.now() for both a slight advantage in performance as well as simpler syntax.

Comment: If the quesiton is a duplicate, mark it as one and don't answer it.