# Difference between Date.now(), new Date().getTime(), and +new Date

Tags: javascript, node.js

I usually use Date.now() to get a timestamp. But lately I had to construct a Date object and learn all the methods. I found that .getTime() returns the same thing as Date.now(). So then whats the point of getTime()? Also, why does this work `+new Date` <-- no () after Date and + before new. And why does it ALSO return the timestamp?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Performance - Date.now() vs Date.getTime()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517359/performance-date-now-vs-date-gettime)

Comment: @Dai It does not. It doesn't explain why and how +new Date works. Thank you for helping

Comment: `+new Date()` just uses `Date`'s implicit conversion to `number`, which is the same as `getTime()`.

Comment: @Dai Thank you for explaining but I also want to know why it works without ()

Comment: If you think _that's_ confusing, check this out... `new Array() instanceof Array === true; Array() instanceof Array === true; new Date() instanceof Date === true; Date() instanceof Date === false` 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Date.now()` gives you the timestamp *right now*.

`Date.getTime()` gives you the timestamp of a date object that may represent a moment in the past or future.

`+new Date` is a slightly confusing way of saying "create a new Date object, then convert it to a number" (identical to `new Number(new Date())`, and when you convert a `Date` to a number, it returns the date's timestamp (i.e. `getTime()`.

Use #1 if you want the timestamp right this second, and use #2 if you want to get the timestamp of a `Date` object you got from somewhere else. Don't use #3 ever - it might look clever, but all you're doing is writing code that's going to confuse yourself or someone else later.

*(Side point, the reason `new Date` works is because you don't actually need parentheses to create an object if you are passing no parameters. You should still use empty parameters though for readability if nothing else.)*

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Is there a reason why String(new Date()) returns the same things as the date's toString method but there is no .toNumber method but still + or Number knows how to convert it into a number?

Comment: @SharedRory the equivalent would probably be `Number(new date)`

Comment: @SharedRory Because `toNumber` isn't very descriptive. The `Date` object has been coded so that when something tries to convert it to a number, it returns the result of `getTime()`, but it would make no sense to call a function called `toNumber` because what would that even mean?

Comment: @purple Sorry I meant there is no .toNumber method on the date yet Number() knows how to convert it to a date. How?

Comment: @purple `new Date` and `new Date()` are the same thing.

Comment: @Abion47 oh so it is an engine level implementation?

Comment: @SharedRory `Date` has defined the property `[Symbol.toPrimitive](hint)`, which is the function that controls when an object is converted to a primitive. In this specific example, converting `Date` to a number will call that property with the parameter "number", and `Date` takes it from there.

Comment: @Abion47 "new Date and new Date() are the same thing", i never said that they aren't :)

Comment: @Abion47 That is super cool. Do you have any resources where I can find more info on Symbol.toPrimitive?

Comment: @purple You said the equivalent would be `new Date`, which implies that it's not `new Date()`. If they are the same thing, they are both correct, but the latter is easier for most people to understand.

Comment: @SharedRory You can check out https://javascript.info/object-toprimitive

Comment: @Abion47 i tried to state that the equivalent to String(new Date()) in terms of instead of converting the date object to a string to a number would be `Number(new date)` or `Number(new date())`, which are both the same

Comment: @SharedRory try to run this example `Number({[Symbol.toPrimitive]() {return 10}})`. As you can see, you can replicate that by yourself. Just crete a Object with the `Symbol.toPrimitive` symbol and try to convert it to a number. Here you can also use the unary plus operator `+{[Symbol.toPrimitive]() {return 10}}`

Answer (score 1):

Like this post already explained ([Performance - Date.now() vs Date.getTime()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517359/performance-date-now-vs-date-gettime)), the difference between `Date.now()` and `Date.getTime()` are mostly just performance, one comment also states that '`Date.now()` doesn’t work in Internet Explorer versions earlier than IE9'.

The method with the unary plus operator, so `+Date.now` works because the unary plus operator **trys** to convert something to a number. You can achiev the same with using  `Number(new Date)`. The parentheses are not necessary because you are not passing any arguments.

See here for more information on why this works that way: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive