# how to make custom templates in Koken

Tags: koken

I'm using Koken and would like to customize the template for text entries by putting the date at the top of the entry.

I hacked a call to [`new Date()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10395287/194309) into the core template file `/admin/templates/text.tmpl.html`

```
<div id="entry-editor">
    <div id="edit-area" data-bind="html: content() || 
        '<p class=\'date\'>' + new Date() + '</p>
         <p class=\'media-row\'><br /></p>'">
    </div>
</div> <!-- close #entry-editor -->
```

This works fine, but I know the perils of hacking core files.

As of this writing, I don't see an answer on the page linked as "[define your own custom template types](http://help.koken.me/customer/portal/articles/828697-custom-templates)" on [help.koken.me](http://help.koken.me/customer/portal/articles/828691-build-your-own-theme).

Without hacking core files, how can I have Koken add a date to the top of each text entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://help.koken.me/customer/portal/questions/1080677-how-to-make-custom-templates-in-koken-

Simply place a `<koken:time>` tag in the [customized theme](http://help.koken.me/customer/portal/articles/898661-customizing-default-themes) template.

For example, in my `/storage/themes/<custom-theme-name>/essay.lens` file:

```
<header>
    <h2>
        <koken:link>{{ essay.title }}</koken:link>
    </h2>
    <p>
        <strong><koken:time show="time" /> <koken:time show="date" /></strong>
    </p>
</header>
```