# Undefined is not a function when calling getTime on new Date

Tags: javascript

I get "undefined is not a function" when trying to run this. What am I missing?

```
function bench(func) {
  var start = new Date.getTime();

  for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    func();
  }

  console.log(func, new Date.getTime() - start);
}

function forLoop() {

    var counter = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      counter += 1;
    }

    return counter;

}

bench(forLoop);
```

Comment: On which line do you get that error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript Date().getTime() is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395242/javascript-date-gettime-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @isherwood - this doesn't look like a dup of that one.  The solution in that case was to add use `new Date()` instead of just `Date()`.  The OP here was already using `new`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use:

```
new Date().getTime();
```

instead of

```
new Date.getTime();
```

---

Here's some explanation of what was doing on.  When you do:

```
new Date.getTime();
```

it looks for the `getTime()` property on the `Date` constructor and that is `undefined` because that property exists on the prototype or actual instantiated objects, not on the constructor itself.  Then it tries to do `new undefined` which obviously doesn't work and gives you the error you saw.

When you do:

```
new Date().getTime();
```

It is essentially doing this:

```
(new Date()).getTime();
```

because of operator precedence and that is what you want.  It will create a new `Date()` object and then call the `.getTime()` method on it.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes you just can't see the obvious. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the Date object before invoking methods on it.

Example:

```
var date = new Date()
start = date.getTime();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3TJLq/